# DevOps Release Pipeline on-premise TaskModuleSqlUtility

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to use DevOps Release Pipeline to release SQL code onto an on-premise SQL Server.

I am able to do this successfully by adding the DevOps agent to one of my servers - But when I try to deploy to a on-premise SQL Server which uses a linked-server to a Sybase database (nothing do do with the database I'm deploying to, the Linked Server is used by a different database on the server) I get the below error in DevOps during the release.

The server I am trying to deploy to has a 'LIB' environment variable in Windows which references "D:\Sybase%SYBASE_OCS%\lib" as the Sybase dlls are used on the machine.

**Release Error:**

> 2021-02-19T12:48:29.0053647Z ##error : Warning as Error: Invalid
> search path 'D:\Sybase%SYBASE_OCS%\lib' specified in 'LIB environment
> variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified. '
>
> (1) : namespace TaskModuleSqlUtility

Is there something I can add to the build or change on the server to get it to deploy?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using self-hosted agent, it need we configure the local machine environment variable.

We need check the environment variable and ensure that the variable path `D:\Sybase%SYBASE_OCS%\lib` exists.

Steps: Open environment variable-> change the LIB variable in both the user and system variables list.